# Stop Function being called multiple times when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using infinite scrolling in my react/redux app and when the user nears the bottom of the page, more contents will load.

But if the user scrolls too fast and just keeps scrolling while content is being fetched from the server, the function responsible for the scroll effect fires multiple times and the API gets the same content, and this causes errors because same items with identical Keys will be loaded.

```
const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

  // Fire Upon Reaching the Bottom of the Page
  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (
      window.innerHeight +
        Math.max(
          window.pageYOffset,
          document.documentElement.scrollTop,
          document.body.scrollTop
        ) >
      document.documentElement.offsetHeight - 100
    ) {
      setIsFetching(true);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

  // Debounce the Scroll Event Function and Cancel it When Called
  const debounceHandleScroll = debounce(handleScroll, 500);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", debounceHandleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", debounceHandleScroll);
  }, [debounceHandleScroll]);

  debounceHandleScroll.cancel();

  // Get More Posts
  const loadMoreItems = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(getMorePosts(moreApiAddress));
    setIsFetching(false);
  }, [dispatch, moreApiAddress]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetching) return;
    loadMoreItems();
  }, [isFetching, loadMoreItems]);
```

This is how the dispatch is being called if the user keeps scrolling botom of the page before the previous content is fetched:

[image]

You can seen the problem in the live app as well: https://reddix.netlify.app/

**Is there any way I can stop that function to fire multiple times when new content is being fetched and/or the user is scrolling too fast?**

Answer (score 0):

Your `handleScroll` function updates state, which causes component's re-render.

That means that you will have new instance of `handleScroll` (and debounceHandleScroll) on each render.

Since you have `debounceHandleScroll` in `useEffect` dependency array, and it changes on each render - you are getting kind of a "endless loop".

Try to use `useCallback` hook for memoizing functions or re-write component and try to move these functions outside of the component.

I mean something like that:

```
const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    if (
      window.innerHeight +
        Math.max(
          window.pageYOffset,
          document.documentElement.scrollTop,
          document.body.scrollTop
        ) >
      document.documentElement.offsetHeight - 100
    ) {
      setIsFetching(true);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }, []);

  // Debounce the Scroll Event Function and Cancel it When Called
  const debounceHandleScroll = useCallback(() => debounce(handleScroll, 500), [handleScroll]);
```

Read more about `useCallback`: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: I'm not sure I quit understand your response. Where would I be supposed to use useCallback?

Comment: I've updated my answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. The function never gets called when I go to the bottom of the page.

Comment: To get this code working you need to update state every time you reach bottom of the page. For example: 

const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

// when you on the bottom
setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);

// and put this state into useEffect deps array
useEffect((...do fetching) => {}, [debounceFunc, page])

Comment: Still not working. Putting debounceFunc and page into the deps arr doesn't do anything at all since I'm not using them in my useEffect. If you look at my original code you'll see that in my get more posts functionality

Comment: I've tried in sandbox, but without lodash - it seems to be working. Check this out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-chandrasekhar-dt0f8

Comment: I have updated my question with an image that Redux Devtools shows and the live version of my app.
In your sandbox, the function does stop calling and when I tried it that way without debounce, multiple actions (same action) got dispatched; although I had just reached the end and didn't scroll any more.